# What is the result of 20--5+-3

Tags: arithmetic

I know that this is potentially very basic but we've actually had a bit of a discussion regarding whether this is 28 or 22! My view is that the order of operations is to add negative five and negative three together and then compute 20-(-8).
However, looking online there is a variety of accepted answers based on computer science and logic etc where addition and subtraction are given equal weighting and, if the calculation is a mixture of addition and subtraction (only) is read from left to right.
Does anybody have a definitive response to this please?

Comment: 22 $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right. Never trust the Internet.

Comment: Do you mean $$20-(-5)+(-3)$$?

Comment: There were no brackets in the question @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: You make an error where you write $-(-5)+(-3) = -8$. Obviously that's not true.

Comment: Oh, $$-(-5)=5$$ and $$5-3=2$$

Comment: @AshishK wouldn't you say that the first minus sign is the subtraction and that the second one 'belongs to' the 5 so you would ignore the first minus sign and compute -5 + -3 as there are no brackets?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner by changing the signs i.e. -(-5) = +5, you have effectively changed the original order of operations though whereby the addition would be done first?

Comment: @RobWakeling the problem is that associativity doesn't hold for subtraction i.e. $(a-b)-c \ne a-(b-c)$.

Comment: As per @Dr.SonnhardGraubner's comment above, there is **only one way** to read the (very badly written) formula $a --b$: we have to read it as $a - (-b)$.

Comment: Thank you all. @MauroALLEGRANZA my point is that by BIDMAS/PEMDAS whatever you want to call it, you would do addition before subtraction. If that's true, the addition would be (-5)+(-3) and then you would do the subtraction 20-(-8)?

Comment: I see no reason for downvoting this question, it provides adequate context, is neither spam, nor too broad, and not unclear in its purpose. No one seems to have provided a duplicate.It might seem to be opinion-based, but is actually not as the OP specifically seems to ask if there is any accepted convention for interpretting it, making "There is no definitive consensus" an acceptable answer if need be.

Comment: Regarding BIDMS, see [Order of operations : Mnemonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Mnemonics) : "These mnemonics may be misleading when written this way. For example, misinterpreting any of the above rules to mean "addition first, subtraction afterward" would incorrectly evaluate the expression $10 − 3 + 2$.
The correct value is $9$ (and not $5$, as if the addition would be carried out first and the result used with the subtraction afterwards)."

Comment: Your question shows clearly how useful is the use of brackets :-)

Comment: In addition to several answers (that I agree with), I always feel it is useful to point out in such 'discussions' that PEDMAS-like rules are a *communication aid*, not a deep law. They set down rules so that we do not have to parenthesize everything. If we didn't have any rules about this we would have to write a quadratic equation as $y = ((3 \times (x^2)) + (7 \times x)) + 3$. But these rules exist for convenience, so if a particular mathematical 'sentence' is confusing, it should just be rephrased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having two minuses after each other like this $1--1$ is bad form, and should be avoided as it is confusing. Regardless, this is always interpreted as $1-(-1)$. In the same way we always have $1+-1 = 1+(-1)$.

This however still does not resolve the other problem you've discovered, since if addition is more important than subtraction, you get
$$
  20-(-5)+(-3) = 20-((-5)+(-3)),
$$
which is plain wrong. Traditionally addition is considered to have the same precedence as subtraction, but if you must have them different, then subtraction must be first. This way we have
$$20-(-5)+(-3) = (20-(-5))+(-3),$$
which is indeed correct.

Be aware that PEMDAS appears to get this wrong, this is because in PEMDAS, you are meant to consider addition and subtraction to have equal precedence, and not addition before subtraction. Note that equal precedence always gives the same answer as having subtraction first. The exact same problem happens with multiplication and division. [Read more](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PEMDAS.html)

I guess PEDMSA just isn't as catchy.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for in terms of whether Addition and Subtraction are equally weighted or if one is given precedence. I guess I could've made that more clear in my question but please forgive the newbie!!

Answer (score 2):

Addition and subtraction are prioritised equally, and evaluated from left to right (note that things aren't nearly as clear-cut with multiplication and division, so there one should *always* use parentheses or fractions to make things clear). Thus the correct order of operations is to start with $20$, subtract $-5$ to get $25$, then add $-3$ to get $22$.

---

Alternatively, the binary operation $-$ can be seen as just a shorthand for "${}+(-1)\times{}$". Using your example again, this would make $20 - -5 + -3$ (which must be read as $20 - (-5) + (-3)$, as discussed in other answers and comments) into
$$
20 + (-1)\times(-5) + (-3)
$$
Doing the multiplication first, we get $20 + 5 + (-3)$, and now the answer is unambiguously $22$. In this interpretation, there isn't really any such thing as "subtraction", which may seem weird, but it actually works pretty well if you get used to it. This is the mental model I use for subtraction some times, but I very rarely actually write it out this way. I just keep the translation in mind every time I write something which "looks like" a subtraction.

Comment: That is very interesting Arthur, a useful interpretation to use with students to reduce the ambiguity. Thank you for your time.